# Ruby on Rails - result printed as an object on my html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is my posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)

        @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    end

    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    private 
        def post_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
        end
end
```

here is my index.html.erb

```
<%= @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="post_wrapper">
        <h2 class="title"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>
        <p class="date"><%= post.created_at.strftime("%B, %d, %Y") %></p>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Here's how the page looks like:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMzMA.png)

Why does that [ ] line show up ?
How do I hide/delete it ?

Comment: Use `<% @posts.each do |post| %>` without the `=`

Comment: Do you mean that's your `show.html.erb` file not `index.html.erb`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `=` to `-`:

```
<%- @posts.each do |post| %>
```

You see in ERB `<%=` means print this into view, where as `<%-` says execute this ruby code.

Since everything in Ruby is an expression, your `@posts.each do |post|; end %>` block returns an array of `@posts`, which is then rendered into your view.

Answer (score 0):

remove `=` like :-

```
<%- @posts.each do |post| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem, you don't need =

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the "=" to "-" or just remove "="

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
```

or

```
<%- @posts.each do |post| %>
```

`<% %>` - Executes the ruby code

`<%- %>` - Avoids the line break after expression

`<%= %>` - Prints into erb

`<%# %>` - Comments out the code